# Oracle XMLTABLE, root with attribute

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xquery

Oracle 12c.

I Have QUERY and XML:

```
 SELECT xt.*
   from  xmltable('/root/persons/person'
         passing xmltype('<root xmlns="import">
  <persons>
    <person>
       <id>John Doe</id>
    </person>
    <person>
       <id>Donald Duck</id>
    </person>
  </persons>
</root>')
         COLUMNS 
           id        VARCHAR2(10)  PATH 'id'
         ) xt
```

and it is not working. 
If i remove xmlns="import" then everything works fine.
I tried to add:

```
xmltable('/root[@xmlns="import"]/persons/person'
```

and still not working. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since namespace is mentioned, add namespace declaration in your xquery. Try the below code.[Refer the link for more details](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2016/03/07/specifying-a-default-namespace-with-xmltable/) Hope it helps.

```
 SELECT xt.*
       from  xmltable( xmlnamespaces(default 'import' ),
  '//persons/person'  passing   xmltype('<root xmlns="import">
      <persons>
        <person>
           <id>John Doe</id>
        </person>
        <person>
           <id>Donald Duck</id>
        </person>
      </persons>
    </root>')
             COLUMNS 
               id        VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'id'
             ) xt
```

Comment: Works as charm! I assumed that if namespace does not appear before any tag like <xmlns:person>, i don't need to add xmlnamespaces clause. 
Thank You!!